Can't apply Rotation by active UV on a Mesh generated by Geometry Nodes with the tissue addon
I'm trying to model a parametric building thanks to Geometry Nodes and the tissue addon.
From a volume, I extract contour curves for each floor, which are processed in GN to set the base mesh to tesselate on.
I'm pretty happy with this worflow since in can modify the base volume, refresh the contour curves, refresh the tesselation, which will update the building facades.
However when doing this the panels are getting a random rotation on each main face of the base volume. The way I found to fix this is by using "Rotation by active UV", but for this to work, i need to convert the processed contour curve to a mesh which kinda breaks the parametric workflow.
Any idea how I could achieve this result without converting to mesh ?

Base Volume

Contour Curves from Volume

Contour Curves to subdivided Mesh (Geometry Node)

Tesselation Result with default rotation (panels are rotated randomly along the main faces)

Tesselation Result after converting processed curve to mesh + Rotation by acvtive UV in Tissue (panels are correctly oriented)

Error message from Tissue addon


Instead of one big 'infographic' image it's better to put multiple images with text above/below them so that it is indexed by search engines. Also please minimize the problem in the .blend file, for example, clearly you don't need 4 cameras to show your problem.

Alright, edited the post, thank you
